# How to convert a named tuple to a unnamed tuple in TypeScript 4.0?

Tags: typescript, tuples

[Since TypeScript 4.0, we have named tuples](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0/#labeled-tuple-elements), which is great:

```
type Fn = (foo: number) => void;

type Foo = Parameters<Fn>;
// type Foo = [foo: number];
```

However, I am facing a situation in which I now have a named tuple but the names are just clutter. I don't want the names.

How can I build a `RemoveNames<T>` utility type that will take `[foo: number]` and return `[number]`?

Note: of course, I need it to work with tuples of any size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those tuple names tend to be pretty sticky, but they do disappear if you prepend/append a non-named element to the tuple.  So one way to do this could be to prepend and then remove some type, like this:

```
type RemoveNames<T extends any[]> = [any, ...T] extends [any, ...infer U] ? U : never
```

That seems to act the way you want:

```
type UnnamedFoo = RemoveNames<Foo>;
// type UnnamedFoo = [number]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdlAvFAFAMwPYYFxTgVwFsAjCAJwEokA+KANwwEsATAbgCgp3RJYskoABQCGZYYQjByAZwA88ahwD0SqD2gx+yANqYceIqTIBdDt3DQAShEIY6EAHLiIcgCpQIADylxm0qMJwINrGtDqBIAA0UAB0ca7GHt4Qvv7aEdFxMYxwaORQAKqJAPyFULhwEPZk7Oa8BXBwzsyaGALWtvZOEnKtiuwqahaFjc2tAtoEJOTGtUA)